# How to set Control Groups in VS-Code / Shortcuts to specific files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to set shortcuts to specific files in VSC like in an RTS game.
I would like to mark specific files (like with Ctrl+1) and then jump to the marked file with that set pathway (like pressing 1). This would allow me to have files I need often on those keys but have them closed in the editor.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can right click a file and pin it. https://youtu.be/dup2f0kXZAk

Answer (score 0):

I have written an extension for this: [File Group](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.FileGroup)

In this first release you have to manually edit the settings and add the groups and files they contain.

The paths mentioned in the lists need to be the full paths as used by the OS. When we have a Multi Root Workspace it is not known which WorkspaceFolder to use.

An example setting is

```json
    "fileGroup.groups": {
      "1": {
        "files": [
          "C:\\Projects\\project1\\Tutorial.md",
          "C:\\Projects\\project2\\API.md"
        ]
      },
      "2": {
        "files": [
          "C:\\Projects\\project2\\Tutorial.md",
          "C:\\Projects\\project3\\Reference.md"
        ]
      }
```

For the groups `"1" ... "9", "0"` there are default Keybindings of `Ctrl+Alt+number`, like `Ctrl+Alt+3` (for mac `Cmd+Alt+number`, like `Cmd+Alt+3`)